# What is the purpose of context in <context : property-placeholder> tag?

Tags: spring, spring-config

What is the purpose of "context" in  tag in Spring?

Why it's not just `<property-placeholder>`. What type of tag is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring divide parts using different schemes, this is part of the [context schema](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-context):

> The context tags deal with ApplicationContext configuration that relates to plumbing - that is, not usually beans that are important to an end-user but rather **beans that do a lot of grunt work** in Spring, such as BeanfactoryPostProcessors